# Is it good to write input in @Before function for JUnit tests?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I am quite new to writing unit tests for Android. I have two questions in mind:

1. Is it good to write your common input for all tests in @Before function on JUnit?
2. Is it a good practice to write two sets of assertion in a single unit test, I mean I assert something then I do some operation and I do assertions again?

Code for reference:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@SmallTest
class TicketDaoTest {
    @get:Rule
    val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
    private lateinit var database: PickDatabase
    private lateinit var ticket: Ticket
    private var timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()

    @Before
    fun initSetup() = runBlockingTest {
        timeStamp = currentTime
        ticket = Ticket(
            "purchaseId", 1, "originName", 1,
            "destName", timeStamp, 1, "Cash", 2,
            44.0, isCancelled = false, synced = false
        )
        database = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
            PickDatabase::class.java
        ).build()
        database.ticketDao().insert(ticket)
    }

    @After
    fun closeDb() = database.close()

    @Test
    fun testGetRecentTickets_returnSingleTicketListBeforeTimeout() = runBlockingTest {
        val tickets = database.ticketDao().getRecentTickets(timeStamp)
        assertThat(tickets, hasSize(1))
        assertThat(tickets, hasItem(ticket))
    }

    @Test
    fun testSetSynced_returnsEmptyList() = runBlockingTest {
        var tickets = database.ticketDao().getUnSyncedTickets()
        assertThat(tickets, hasSize(1))
        assertThat(tickets, hasItem(ticket))
        database.ticketDao().setSynced(listOf(ticket.purchaseId))
        tickets = database.ticketDao().getUnSyncedTickets()
        assertThat(tickets, empty())
   } 

    @Test
    fun testRemoveTicketFromDatabase_returnsEmptyList() = runBlockingTest {
        var tickets = database.ticketDao().getRecentTickets(timeStamp)
        assertThat(tickets, hasSize(1))
        database.ticketDao().removeTicketFromDatabase(ticket.purchaseId)
        tickets = database.ticketDao().getRecentTickets(timeStamp)
        assertThat(tickets, empty())
    }
}
```

Comment: there isn't really a right or a wrong answer to this, it'll depend on opinion and the standards followed by the team

Answer (score 1):

There are no universal rules for how to write unit tests.

However there are some recommendations and best practices that can help you in a long run.

These recommendations are quite different person from person but all of them have some variations of these rules.

1. Test One Thing at a Time in Isolation - this basically means that tests should not depend on each other, each test should stand on it's own. One test should not be changed by other. You can take away that running the setup in `@Before` means that one test cannot modify the data for the other test. But I see you are creating in memory DB in there. That can be slow and if you have hundreds of these tests it could take a while, so maybe best approach here would be to create the db in `@BeforeClass` and just reset the data in `@After`.
2. AAA Rule: Arrange, Act, Assert - test should start with a arrange section, where you prepare your data, followed by act section where you do your actions and finished by the assert section where you do your asserts. You are basically making arrange, act, asset, act, assert. That could be fine in some cases but as rule I am trying to avoid it and stick to AAA structure.